# How can I preview all sublime text 3 themes before installing?

Tags: themes, sublime-text-3

From my understanding from within sublime u have a few default themes/colourscheme. To get new ones you need to ctrl+shift+p then select the install packages. Then from there u can install various themes/colourschemes. You don't seem able to preview them in this tab though. You have to install them first...and then uninstall if you don't like them.

This is bothersome so I've been trying to lookup individual themes in google images and by typing in any little info bits I get on the install rectangle to view them on github individually or wherever.

This isn't working though, I really need a clean selection of images showing all the themes/colourschemes to be chosen from. IS there any way to facilitate this kind of selection process? From within sublime or some kind of site that shows them all?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While not having *all* themes included, [Colorsublime plugin](https://github.com/Colorsublime/Colorsublime-Plugin) and related [website](https://colorsublime.github.io/) let you preview *many* color schemes.

As of October 2019, the plugin downloads about 380 different themes and lets you preview them right in the editor, before accepting.